# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, server, host

I created a web api using c#, but when I pushed the code in production, users are getting the following error

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

when I debug with all possibilities, I find that my Route contains something like this

```
[Route("{string}/{int=-1}/{int2=-1}")]
```

but when I debug, I am not getting the error in `localhost`,

what might be the issue here?

Comment: are you able to see errors in more details in console or network tab?

Comment: No i am not able to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what the exact issue and why is it persisting.

basically, it means that the remote side closed the connection (most commonly happens during TCP/IP `RST` packet) and the reason can vary:

- You are sending malformed data to the application
- The network link between the client and server is going down for some reason
- You have triggered a bug in the third-party application that caused it to crash
- The third-party application has exhausted system resources

If you said that when you debug everything is working, I'd recommend using the wireshark first, outside of debug mode, before taking any action in order to estimate the cause for the issue and possible solution in order to solve it.